# Add Checkbox to Wordpress Login Form - Terms and Conditions

Tags: php, wordpress, logging

Cannot find where to add validation for a checkbox on wordpress login form. I have an additional checkbox set up called 'terms' that I need the user to check each time they want to log in.

Problem is that I cannot stop wordpress logging in if they don't check it. Where it the login code.

There is also a plugin installed that may be complicating matters called them-my-login.

I have all the code in front of me, just tell me what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is fairly old but I just stumbled across it and was able to look at the codex and work out a solution. Hope this helps somebody. Thanks to @Jason for pointing in the right direction.

This code will need to be added to your theme's `functions.php` file:

```
<?php

// As part of WP authentication process, call our function
add_filter('wp_authenticate_user', 'wp_authenticate_user_acc', 99999, 2);

function wp_authenticate_user_acc($user, $password) {
    // See if the checkbox #login_accept was checked
    if ( isset( $_REQUEST['login_accept'] ) && $_REQUEST['login_accept'] == 'on' ) {
        // Checkbox on, allow login
        return $user;
    } else {
        // Did NOT check the box, do not allow login
        $error = new WP_Error();
        $error->add('did_not_accept', 'You must accept the terms and conditions' );
        return $error;
    }
}

// As part of WP login form construction, call our function
add_filter ( 'login_form', 'login_form_acc' );

function login_form_acc(){
    // Add an element to the login form, which must be checked
    echo '<label><input type="checkbox" name="login_accept" id="login_accept" /> I agree</label>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer Patrick Moore gave did not work for me, but I did modify it to provide a valid solution. This may be because he answered it back in 2013, and now the code has changed. I changed the filter to login_form_middle, and modified the function at the end as a variable, and then passing the value back through a return:

```
<?php

// As part of WP authentication process, call our function
add_filter('wp_authenticate_user', 'wp_authenticate_user_acc', 99999, 2);

function wp_authenticate_user_acc($user, $password) {
    // See if the checkbox #login_accept was checked
    if ( isset( $_REQUEST['login_accept'] ) && $_REQUEST['login_accept'] == 'on' ) {
        // Checkbox on, allow login
        return $user;
    } else {
        // Did NOT check the box, do not allow login
        $error = new WP_Error();
        $error->add('did_not_accept', 'You must accept the terms and conditions' );
        return $error;
    }
}

// As part of WP login form construction, call our function
add_filter ( 'login_form_middle', 'login_form_acc' );

function login_form_acc(){
    // Add an element to the login form, which must be checked
    $termsLink = '<label><input type="checkbox" name="login_accept" id="login_accept" /> I agree</label>';
    return $termsLink;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[WordPress Filters/Actions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/) are your friend.

Take a look at:

- [admin_init](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_init#Example%3a_Access_control)
- [wp_login](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_login)